# Only 118 lines has been printed in Panda's dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tweepy

I have tried to scrape twitter data from a specific date by using tweepy and panda's dataframe. But there is only printed fixed 118 rows of recent data. How can I scrape all data by using this code ? Another problem is that I can't filter data between two specific date, for example: 2019-01-01 to 2020-01-01. What is the code for this spefic task? Please help me, I desperately need this solution. Here is my code:

```
import tweepy
import re
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import collections
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from textblob import TextBlob
import os
import datetime
import sys

consumer_key = " "
consumer_secret = " "
access_token = " "
access_token_secret = " "

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True,wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

date_since = "2019-01-01"
date_until = "2020-01-01"
                     
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                       q="Shopify (canada OR canadian)",
                       since = date_since,
                       #until = date_until,
                       tweet_mode="extended",
                       lang="en").items()

user_data = [[tweet.created_at, tweet.user.name, tweet.user.location,
              tweet.full_text, TextBlob(tweet.full_text).sentiment[0],
              'Positive' if TextBlob(tweet.full_text).sentiment[0] > 0 
              else 'Negative' if TextBlob(tweet.full_text).sentiment[0] < 0
              else 'Nuetral'] for tweet in tweets]

    
df = pd.DataFrame(data=user_data,
                        columns=['Created At', "User", 'Location', 'Text', 'Sentiment', 'Polarity'])
    
df.to_excel("output.xlsx") 

df.head(1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [twitter documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets), your search api can fetch only previous 1 week of data from **until** date. Also, **since** parameter has been deprecated. You can find all the parameters on twitter's documentation page.